# Only background and mouse pointer after login Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login, desktop-environments

**(Update Dec 8th, 2021: I have found the root cause. Thank you all the same. I am posting the root cause.)**

Recently I work with a Ubuntu 18.04. One day, after login desktop, there are only background and mouse pointer.

But I still can SSH to the system. **I create a new account by SSH and I can log in desktop with that new account.**

I log in to the bad original account by SSH and do the following:

```
mv .cache .cache.old
mv .config .config.old
mv .local .local.old
sudo reboot
```

After this, the problem remains, i.e., I can log in to my new account to the desktop, but if I log in to my old account, there are only background and mouse pointer.

How to bring my old desktop account back?

By the way, my Ubuntu 18.04 is a VM in VMWare. I installed the default desktop environment and it works well. Yesterday I installed a Robot Operation System (ROS) in it, and installed Shadowsocks, I tried to run a self-written script to start Shadowsocks client at startup by adding service approach and @reboot in crontab approach but failed, but I can manually make proxy works by Privoxy and Shadowsocks, and I set proxy of my desktop environment. But the problem occured at next reboot.

Comment: @guiverc, it is not intentionally clean. I installed the default desktop environment of Ubuntu 18.04 and it works before. But yesterday, after I installed the Robot Operation System (ROS) and shadowsocks client, and tried to start self-writing shadowsocks client startup script with failure by service approach and later by @ reboot in crontab approach, and set desktop proxy manually to use Privoxy and shadowsocks, it becomes clean at later reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the root cause, an incorrect config in my .bashrc file. It is a long story. I write them below:

This Ubuntu is a VM in VMWare Windows 10. And simultaneously I am trying WSL GUI. In .bashrc of my WSL account, I added:

```
export DISPLAY=host_ip:0.0
```

With an X11 server (VcXsrv) on host, I can run GUI programs on WSL.
After this success, I tried this on bash session to my VM Ubuntu in host SecureCRT, and it is also a success.

Then I wrongly added the same `export DISPLAY=xxx:0.0` configuration in .bashrc of my VM Ubuntu account.
On the new login after this, I cannot use the GUI of my VM Ubuntu and without knowing why. And I asked here.

It is a per-user-account problem. But it cannot be solved by deleting ~/.cache ~/.config ~/.local because the root cause is in .bashrc.
I found the root cause by accident.

That is the full story. Sorry for the trouble. Thank you all!